# How to perform nested query in firebase realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I fetched data from firebase database, inside OnDataChange method I want to perform another query based on the data I fetched previously. Before going to another activity I fetched all my data using a callback function MyCallback. Here listAllRequest contains expected data but userMap contains null. How can I ensure userMap contains data before going to another activity?

```java
public void readRequestData(final Outgoing.MyCallback myCallback) {
        groupDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(user.getUid()).child("outgoing");
        userInfoRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("UserInfo");

        groupDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                listAllRequest.clear();

                for(DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {

                    final BookRequestData bookRequestData = childSnapshot.getValue(BookRequestData.class);
                    listAllRequest.add(bookRequestData);

                    userInfoRef.child(bookRequestData.getOwnerId()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            User user=dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                            userMap.put(bookRequestData.getReqId(),user);
                            Log.e("outgoing",user.getName());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

                }
                myCallback.onCallback(listAllRequest);

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });

    }
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to read data a single time, rather than listen for changes over time.  In that case, you should use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `addValueEventListener`.  Right now, you're adding listeners and never removing them, which could cause problems.

Comment: I tried addListenerForSingleValueEvent and removed listener but still getting null .